# Оставлять полную структуру документа после работы в CKEDITOR

Tags: ckeditor

Когда загружаешь в редактор целый здоровый шаблон с полноценной структурой,то на выходе получаю все кроме прежней структуры.То есть было так перед работой с редактором:

```html
<html>
  <head><link src='путь'>
      <title></title> стили и так далее прописаны
  </head>
  <body><p>Куча тексту</p></body>
</html>
```

После:

```
<link rel='путь'>
<title></title>
<p></p>
```

И еще что интересно - `<title>` на выходе пустой

Вопрос - как сделать так чтобы структура оставалась прежней

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для полного редактирования страницы используйте следующий код:

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'textarea_id', {
    fullPage: true, //включаем редактор страницы целиком
    allowedContent: true //отключаем фильтрацию контента
});
```

[Информация](http://ckeditor.com/ckeditor_4.3_beta/samples/plugins/wysiwygarea/fullpage.html)

Comment: буду рад если посмотрите на эту проблему пр даному редактору - http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/468097/%d0%9f%d1%83%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%b2-ckeditor