# Пути в CKEDITOR

Tags: ckeditor

При подгрузке шаблона\просто страницы в данном редакторе не отображаются изображения, а иногда и теряются стили благодаря расположению папок...

То есть обычно такие пути `path/style.css`, а нужно `path/path/style.css`

Есть такой параметр как `config.basehref`, но так как папки динамичные, то необходима возможность как-то закинуть в `basehref` **в само текстовое поле**. Чего у меня не получилось.
Прикладываю код

```
     <form action='act.php' method='POST'>
        <textarea name="editor1" id="editor1" rows="10" cols="80">
         <?php
         include "$papka/$page1";
         ?>
        </textarea>
        // Следующее поле имеет смысл редактировать только если вторая форма была заполнена & или названием,но не 0
        <br>
        <textarea name="editor2" id="editor1" rows="10" cols="80">
        <?php
           if (!$page2 == 0) {
        include "$papka/$page2";
           }
         ?>

        </textarea>

        <script>
            // Replace the <textarea id="editor1"> with a CKEditor
            // instance, using default configuration
           CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
           fullPage: true,
           baseHref = '<?php echo $papka; ?>',
       });
        CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor2', {
           fullPage: true,
           baseHref = '<?php echo $papka; ?>',
       });
        </script>
        <input type='submit'>
    </form>
```

Comment: а через `.htaccess` не вариант?

Comment: @Saidolim Не совсем понимаю как это сделать при условии что каждый раз другой шаблон и другая папка